# What do "hinc est quod eo veluti" and "Thesini" mean in this passage?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

The text I need help translating is:

> In hoc loco, quia catena actuum divinorum sibi mutuo succedentium in procuratione salutis hominum nectitur talis, quae ab absoluto decreto originem ducere videtur, hinc est, quod eo veluti triario milite & principali ac nervoso, prout loquuntur, loco, vti solent ad hanc suam Thesini stabiliendum.

([Full text available here](https://books.google.com/books?id=7Kw7vHwzTKsC&pg=RA1-PA192&lpg=RA1-PA192))

I have two questions:

- What does the phrase, "hinc est quod eo veluti" mean?
- Also, what is "Thesini"? I have no idea what that means.

Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing the sentence--I can't find a verb for the main sentence. Regarding the second question, the surrounding context shows that he's using the Latinized Greek word "thesis" (with the inflections "thesi" and "thesin" on the same page), but I'm not sure how "thesini" would fit into that paradigm.

Answer (score 3):

After looking at the context, this is obviously part of a much wider explanation. It begins *in hoc loco*, referring to the particular biblical quotation (from Romans 9, *vv*. x, xi), though the connection is a bit hazy to my mind. The sense is somewhat obscured by the unnecessarily flowery language, but is something like:

'In this (verse), since such a series of divinely inspired actions following one after another, apparently based on an absolute promise, is connected with managing the wellbeing of men; hence, because in that (verse), just like they say, just as they are accustomed to use a third-rank soldier as [if he were] both a first ranker and a keen one, [it is suitable] for supporting this, their own proposition.'

The phrase *hinc est quod eo veluti* indicates a justification for what follows. *Thesis* (a feminine noun) is, as @brianpck says, a borrowing from Greek to mean something like 'proposition'.